# How do I display more decimals in the output console?

Tags: c++, console

I want to output the value of a double in it's full precision. However, when using the cout function, it only displays the first 6 digits even though there is around 15-16 digits of precision.

How do I get my program to display the entire value, including the magnitude (power) component?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the `setprecision()` manipulator:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setprecision/

You can also force scientific notation with the `scientific` manipulator:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/scientific/

```
cout << scientific << setprecision(15) << my_number << endl;
```

Answer (score 9):

you could use something like this :

```
#include <iomanip>

cout << setprecision (9) << double_value << endl;
```

more iomanipulators, [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/)

Comment: what if you wanted it to be fully precise. but obviously turn the number such as 7.3333333 to lets say 7.33

Comment: The is no equivalent of %g format of printf.  And that format doesn't give you what some other languages give: the shortest string which reads back to the original number.

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for [`setprecision`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setprecision/) (code taken from link):

```
int main () {
  double f =3.14159;
  cout << setprecision(15) << f << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just in case you missed it down below, you can also use the scientific io-manipulator to force scientific notation if you desire.