# How can I improve the precision of a double in c++?

Tags: c++

I would like to improve the precision of a double. It seems the precision of double and float is the same. 
(I also need a better precision for my future c++ plans.)

I have no clue how to do this.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double fraction1 = 0.123467890123456789;
    float fraction2 = 0.123467890123456789;
    cout << fraction1 << endl;
    cout << fraction2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This yields:

0.123468 
0.123468

I would have expected something like a precision of 10 or more digits.

Comment: Those variables store more digits than `cout` prints by default. Try [`std::setprecision`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision).

Comment: There is a big difference between the precision of a real number and how that number is displayed.

Comment: Other possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1231685/1896169 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/554063/1896169 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/4217510/1896169

Comment: You should also look into [`std::numeric_limits<T>::max_digits10`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max_digits10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You are observing the default output precision of an `ostream`, not the precision of a `double`.

Use [`std::setprecision`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) to get the output you want.